# flutter_bloc: Bloc doesn't rebuild itself

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm re-writing a very simple application to calculate averages, however I have a hard time with BLoC pattern.

I'm trying to retrieve a number from a TextFormField, pass it to the event, process it and send it as a state. The problem is that I don't know how to show it after retrieving it from the state. I'm trying to show it using a ternary operator, however it doesn't work.

Here's how the app looks like, I want the number from the TextFormField to be sent to the event and being processed in bloc file and I want to to be shown as three ??? question marks. 
[image]

### Arithmetic Average Screen:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import '../shared/custom_card.dart';

import '../bloc/average_bloc.dart';

class ArithmeticAverageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ArithmeticAverageScreenState createState() => _ArithmeticAverageScreenState();
}


class _ArithmeticAverageScreenState extends State<ArithmeticAverageScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('arithmetic_average_title').tr(),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<AverageBloc, AverageState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AverageInitial) {
            return buildListViewWithCards(context, state.average);
          }
        },
      )
    );
  }
}

Widget buildListViewWithCards(BuildContext context, String average) {
  final _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        CustomCard(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                title: Text('arithmetic_average_help').tr(),
                subtitle: Text('arithmetic_average_help_content').tr(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 16.0),
        CustomCard(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('arithmetic_average_your_grades', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5).tr(),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Text('arithmetic_average_type_grades', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6).tr(),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 140.0,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                            decimal: true,
                            signed: false
                          ),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty || value == ',' || value == '.') {
                              return 'arithmetic_average_text_form_field_error'.tr();
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          controller: _textFieldController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'arithmetic_average_textfield_hint'.tr(),
                            hintText: '5'
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            submitGrade(context, _textFieldController.text);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('arithmetic_average_add_button').tr(),
                        color: Colors.teal[300],
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 16.0),
        CustomCard(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('arithmetic_average_your_average', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5).tr(),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Center(
                  child: average == null ? Text('???', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4) : Text(average, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4) // Here is the problem
                )
              ],
            )
          )
        )
      ],
    )
  );
}

void submitGrade(BuildContext context, String average) {
  final averageBloc = BlocProvider.of<AverageBloc>(context);
  averageBloc.add(GetArithmeticAverage(average, context));
}
```

### Arithmetic Average State

```dart
part of 'average_bloc.dart';

abstract class AverageState extends Equatable {
  const AverageState();
}

class AverageInitial extends AverageState {
  final String average;

  const AverageInitial(this.average);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [average];
}

class AverageLoaded extends AverageState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

### Arithmetic Average Event

```dart
part of 'average_bloc.dart';

abstract class AverageEvent extends Equatable {
  const AverageEvent();
}

class GetArithmeticAverage extends AverageEvent {
  final String average;
  final BuildContext context;

  const GetArithmeticAverage(this.average, this.context);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [average];
}
```

### Arithmetic Average Bloc

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

part 'average_event.dart';
part 'average_state.dart';

class AverageBloc extends Bloc<AverageEvent, AverageState> {
  String average;

  @override
  AverageState get initialState => AverageInitial(average);

  @override
  Stream<AverageState> mapEventToState(
    AverageEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is GetArithmeticAverage) {
      String locale = Localizations.localeOf(event.context).toString();


      if (locale == 'en_US') {
        if (event.average.contains(',')) {
          average = event.average.replaceAll(',', '.');
        }
        else if (locale == 'pl_PL') {
          if (event.average.contains('.')) {
            average = event.average.replaceAll('.', ',');
          }
        }
      }
      yield AverageInitial(average);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem actually? Is it constantly displaying three question marks?

Comment: @Limbou Yes, I want to display the average instead of three question marks, but if there’s no average, I want it to be three question marks.

Comment: Try to make breakpoints at `yield AverageInitial(average)` and see what are the value of average. Also try making breakpoint in build method, where you check if there is an average or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add correct props in `AverageInitial` to let bloc know that's different `AverageInitial`. The code you provided didn't use equatable correctly.

Try change to:

```
class AverageInitial extends AverageState {
  final String average;

  const AverageInitial(this.average);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [average];
}
```

Comment: I changed the code, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @szakes1 Debug bloc with [BlocDelegate](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/BlocDelegate-class.html), then You'll know If this is the problem of bloc.